# Unable to see chrome source maps

Tags: gwt

My eclipse console output says i have enabled source maps.
I have also ticked thhe source maps option in chrome. I am running  the latest stable chrome version and using gwt 2.5.0. I do not get  the java code.I'm trying out the starter app .No mods to it.
EDIT: And  i have also tried deleting the gwtunitcache folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7725), upgrade to GWT 2.5.1.